# Неудачный поиск максимального числа, используя вложенные If и else

Tags: java

необходимо найти максимальное число.

```java
public class Test {
    public static int max2(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        int result = d;
        if (a > b) {
            if (a > c) {
                if (a > d) {
                    result = a;
                }
            }
        } else if (b > c) {
            if (b > d) {
                result = b;
            }
        } else if (c > d) {
            result = c;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(max2(3, 2, 5, 4));
        System.out.println(max2(3, 2, 4, 1));
    }
}
```

получаю результат: 4 и 1
Уже 4 часа мучаюсь с дебаггером, не могу понять где у меня ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if (a > c) {
            if (a > d) {
                result = a;
            }
        }
```

А если `c` больше чем `a`?

---

```
public static int max2(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  int result = a;
  if (b > result)
    result = b;
  if (c > result)
    result = c;
  if (d > result)
    result = d;
  return result;
}
```